# Get whole number from float

Tags: lazarus, freepascal

I have number: 12.73486
I would like to get only whole number: 12.
Could you help me? I don't want to round but cut only for whole number.

Comment: What behaviour do you want for negative numbers? As it stands your question is ill defined.

Comment: In FreePascal and Delphi, you would use `Trunc()`, which returns the integral portion only as an integer. It does not require the `math` unit.

Comment: @KenWhite `Trunc` will necessarily (try to) return an `integer` value. If the magnitude is expected to become very large, i. e. outside of the `‑maxInt..maxInt` range, you’ll choose Delphi’s/FPC’s [`system.int`](https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/system/int.html) which returns a `real` value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like in most programming languages, you can use [floor()](https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/math/floor.html)

Answer (score 0):

Floor function is correct as Emiliopelaez said, but I "believe" you must remember to add the "math" unit to your uses statement